# Use Gulp-imagemin with imagemin-jpeg-recompress plugin?

Tags: jpeg, gulp, gulp-imagemin

I'm just experimenting with Gulp to simply optimize images. I find that [imagemin-jpeg-recompress](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imagemin-jpeg-recompress) reduces JPGs more than the default optimizer that comes with  [gulp-imagemin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-imagemin). I'm wondering if there is a way to use `gulp-imagemin` but swap out the `jpegtran` plugin for the the `imagemin-jpeg-recompress`.

I can't seem to find any detailed docs as to how this might work together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question. I could be wrong but it seems it's an easy process. Simply `require` the plugin (in this case, I want to use `imagemin-jpeg-recompress` plugin). Then specify the plugin to use within `imagemin` via the `use` property of `imagemin`. I believe this will override the bundled `jpegtran` optimizer that comes with `imagemin`.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
var imageminJpegRecompress = require('imagemin-jpeg-recompress');

gulp.task('optimize', function () {
  return gulp.src('src/images/*')
    .pipe(imagemin({
      use:[imageminJpegRecompress({
        loops:4,
        min: 50,
        max: 95,
        quality:'high' 
      })]
    }))
});
```

Answer (score 4):

In the new versions (3.x) of gulp-imagemin, the solution above doesn't work. The reason is that they changed how plugins are declared and configured to an array syntax and scoped arguments.

The API change is [documented in Release 3.0.0](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-imagemin/releases/tag/v3.0.0)

```
gulp.task('default', () => {
    return gulp.src('src/images/*')
-       .pipe(imagemin({
-           interlaced: true,
-           progressive: true,
-           optimizationLevel: 5,
-           svgoPlugins: [{removeViewBox: false}]
-       }))
+       .pipe(imagemin([
+           imagemin.gifsicle({interlaced: true}),
+           imagemin.mozjpeg({progressive: true}),
+           imagemin.optipng({optimizationLevel: 5}),
+           imagemin.svgo({plugins: [{removeViewBox: false}]})
+       ]))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/images'));
 });
```

Noting that also "if you pass in an array of plugins you need to explicitly pass in every plugin you want, not just the ones you want to change options for."

New versions of imagemin-jpeg-recompress (5.x) follow this API.

Putting it all together, using the default plugins (except jpegtran, which we override with jpeg-recompress), the answer above can be formatted as follows:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
var imageminJpegRecompress = require('imagemin-jpeg-recompress');

gulp.task('optimize', function () {
  return gulp.src('src/images/*')
    .pipe(imagemin([
      imagemin.gifsicle(),
      imageminJpegRecompress({
        loops:4,
        min: 50,
        max: 95,
        quality:'high' 
      }),
      imagemin.optipng(),
      imagemin.svgo()
    ]))
});
```

[Relevant discussion on gulp-imagemin github issue tracker](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-imagemin/issues/190)

Comment: Thanks for linking the release notes. I missed the change back in May and didn't turn up the new syntax after an hour of searching. 

Comment: Yes, thank you! I've been searching for hours on this, I confirm the latter worked perfect.